# How to tell compiler no one is allowed to make a instance of class in C++ or C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

There are two project, one in C++ CLI and the other in C#.
C++ CLI assembly is referenced in my C# project

I have this class in C++ CLI:

```
public class ref Player{
    private:
    int id_;
    public:
    Player(int Id) : id_(Id){}
}
```

In some other part of this project I define a array of allowed players.

In C# I want be able only to access the array and protect programmer to create another instance of class `Player` in C#.

Imaginary in code :
In C# I want :

```
PlayersArray[0].dostuff();
```

In C# I don't want :

```
Player x = new Player(1);
x.dostuff();
```

Comment: In C# you can define the class `Player` as [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(v=vs.110).aspx), this will prevent it from creating new instance of the class, but I am not sure if it will suit your other requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it instantiatable in C++ but not C#, make the constructor `internal` to the C++/CLI assembly:

```
internal:
    Player(int Id) : id_(Id) {}
```

This makes the constructor visible only to the assembly it is defined in, so you can construct the objects within the C++/CLI assembly but not outside.

To make it instantiatable by nothing outside the `Player` class, make the constructor `private`:

```
private:
    Player(int Id) : id_(Id) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be to define an *interface* for the functionality you want to expose, then have `Player` implement that interface, and now don't make `Player` public.

This forces the consumer to only interact with `Player` via the interface, and of course, you cannot construct an interface.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, a better solution than simply using access modifiers and exposing the class. Having a non-public class implement a public interface lets you clearly show your intention, and easily allows you to change your implementation or provide alternate implementations without requiring usage code changes.

Answer (score 2):

Make a constructor private? In C++ also make a copy constructor private...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be marking the constructor of Player as private and creating and populating the PlayersArray from inside the Player class

Answer (score 0):

You want to control the creation of objects, which is a perfect job for the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Pattern)!

You could create an collection holding those values, make the constructor private and create a static variable holding the global player data:

```
public class Player
{
    // For access
    public static IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; private set; }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    // Private constructor
    private Player(int Id)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    // Factory method
    public static void CreatePlayers(int NumPlayers)
    {
        // Only create players collection once!
        if (Players != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        Players = new List<Player>(NumPlayers);

        for (int i = 0; i < NumPlayers; i++)
        {
            var player = new Player(i);
            player.Players = Players;
            Players.Add(player);
        }
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Even though this is C#, it should be easy to translate it to CLI/C++. Make sure you also declare the copy-constructor as private. Also the other answers mention the `internal` accessor, but I personally try to prevent using `internal` since it breaks the traditional OOP design.